# ViewDoesNotExist while rendering

Tags: django

I have split up `views.py` into two files, organized thus:

```
views/
  __init__.py
  public.py
  private.py
```

In one view (in public) I render a template which has the following:

```
<a href='{% url app.views.private.login_view %}'>Login</a>
```

I get the following error when loading the url:

> ### TemplateSyntaxError at /
>
> Caught `ViewDoesNotExist` while rendering:
>   Could not import `app.views.private.app.views`. Error was: No module
>   named `app.views`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the views working normally? What version of django are you using?

Comment: If I remove the `{% url %}` it works fine. Django 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try naming your url and then using that name inside the `{% url ... %}` tag, like so:

```
#urls.py
url(r'^xyz/abc/$','app.views.private.login_view', name='login_view'),

#login_view.html (template-code)
<a href='{% url login_view %}'>Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [naming your url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), then using the name in the `{% url %}` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `{% load url from future %}` ? If so you will need to put quotes around your url so that it is `{% url 'app.views.private.login_view' %}`

The release notes for Django 1.3 explains it.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi